# flask, cannot migrate. 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI').replace('%', '%%')) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make app following this tutorial https://www.codementor.io/olawalealadeusi896/restful-api-with-python-flask-framework-and-postgres-db-part-1-kbrwbygx5 
But I'v stucked on running migrations with "python manage.py db migrate" I'm getting this errors, can't recognize their meaning, and don't know how to solve this, because I'm completely new in python.

```
FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
```

'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    manager.run()
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 417, in run
    result = self.handle(argv[0], argv[1:])
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 386, in handle
    res = handle(*args, **config)
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_script/commands.py", line 216, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 95, in wrapped
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 215, in migrate
    version_path=version_path, rev_id=rev_id)
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 214, in revision
    script_directory.run_env()
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 489, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 98, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 173, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "migrations/env.py", line 27, in <module>
    'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI').replace('%', '%%'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

It looks like the main problem in this line in migrations>env.py

```
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', current_app.config.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI').replace('%', '%%'))
```

but "migrations" directory was auto-generated after running "python manage.py db init"
And I'm not sure that it can contain any errors

Answer (score 0):

Following [your example](https://www.codementor.io/olawalealadeusi896/restful-api-with-python-flask-framework-and-postgres-db-part-1-kbrwbygx5).
`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` [variable get from system environment](https://gist.github.com/olawalejarvis/cf02f37653ff6a63008a915b7a757276#file-config-py-L12)

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')
```

So. You need run the following from your terminal to set system environment variables

```
$ export DATABASE_URL= postgres://name:password@houst:port/blog_api_db
```

Comment: yes, I'v done it already and have checked that this variables has been saved correctly running "prinenv" command. But it was before. Now "printenv" returns result without those three variables. Is it possible, this variables to disappear after computer reloading, or something else? Now I'v added this variables again and all works fine.

Comment: I have checked it again, and yes, this three variables completely disappears from pipenv after computer restart. Should I export them every time before begin to work, or there is some other way?